# Help translating this FH Bradley quote from English to Vulcan

Tags: star-trek, vulcan

I'm confused at how to get the proper phrasing in Vulcan because the English grammar seems self-referencing for me to get the order right.

the quote by FH Bradley is:

> The one self-knowledge worth having is to know one’s own mind.

and wanted to translate it, but "worth having is" seems like three verbs in a row, then "one's own" seems like I could omit 'one's' and nam-tor can be stated by describing the noun.

Is it

> Kerik ma fai-tukh t’shai goh fai-tor kashek t’du.

or am I missing it?

Comment: Please ask your questions in English.

Comment: There [appears to be a consensus that requests for the translation from fictional languages to English are on-topic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8166/5930), so I suppose requests for translations from English to fictional languages should also be on-topic.  If there is disagreement about this perhaps a new question should be opened on Meta?

Comment: (Regardless, as Mooz already pointed out, the question itself - including the title - should be in English.)

Comment: How do you figure "three verbs in a row"? Do you think "worth" is a verb?

Comment: Is there actually a Vulcan language that's been worked out? As far as I was aware, it was only Klingon that had been turned into a full-on language.

Comment: asked in english - edited my question lol - i mistakenly assumed if one understood the title they would be better inclined to answer the question, of which is now proof of the matter, since nobody answered - and to the question if it's actually a language - i asked the question IN said language. - perhaps this is the wrong forum

Comment: An actual Vulcan language appears to be being developed by a small, fan-run group calling themselves the [Vulcan Language Institute](http://www.vli-online.org/vlif.htm). There are a couple of Klingon speakers around here, but Klingon is an officially licensed and developed language. Vulcan is not official, and the fan group doing it is small, so most people don't know it exists. You might be well served by including a link to their website in your question. In the end, I'd think you're probably better off emailing them directly or maybe asking them on their Facebook page.